# Load page using jQuery's .load()

Tags: jquery, html

After trying to get this to work for hours I turn to you guys.

I want to load a page into a `div` tag using jQuery. The page I'm loading has a HTML5 media player:

```
<h3> {{ title }} </h3>
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="/static/media/{{ song }}" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

when I load the page directly it works fine. When I do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( ".song" ).click(function() {
        alert('hello')
    });

    $("#mp").load("/playsong?song_id=53847b72936aa27d640039f7");

});
</script>
```

It works fine (and the hello message works!)

But when I put the load command inside the `.click()` event, it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( ".song" ).click(function() {
        alert('hello')
        $("#mp").load("/playsong?song_id=53847b72936aa27d640039f7");
    });

});
</script>
```

I am using flask on the backend and in all cases the code on the backend gets executed.

Comment: missing `;` after alert. Not sure if that could be causing any issue

Comment: Errors in the browser console?

Comment: @cr0ss Ya not the issue, added automatically by js interpreter

Comment: Does your templating engine process the ajaxed data.

Comment: Instead of load try $("#mp").html("/playsong?song_id=53847b72936aa27d640039f7");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $(document).on("load","#mp","/playsong?song_id=53847b72936aa27d640039f7");
        $( ".song" ).click(function() {
            alert('hello')
            $( "#mp" ).trigger( "load" );
        });

    });
</script>
```

let me know if this works, 'cause I have a backup answer!